# Error adding jslink property to a view via REST

Tags: rest, jslink

I'm attempting to add a jslink script to a Promoted links list via rest.

Despite jsLink referenced as a property of [SP.View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245588.aspx), I get the following error:

`The property 'jsLink' does not exist on type 'SP.View'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.`

Snippet

`var changeData = {
  '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.View' },
  'DefaultView': true,
  "jsLink": jslUrl,
  'RowLimit': 5,
};`

`$.ajax({
  url: thisViewUrl,
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(changeData),
  headers: {
  "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
  "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
}`

Comment: Is SharePoint On Line? Do you see the jslink property via browser?

Comment: OnPrem. I do see jsLink property on the list.